# Matlab: Displaying class-file details in file browser

Tags: matlab, class

I'm wondering why matlab does not display access types of class methods and attributes in the preview detail window when selecting a file in the file browser!? Is this the default behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Is this a feature that exists but isn't working for you or a feature you'd like that MATLAB doesn't have?  Also, a screenshot might help explain what you want.

Comment: Do you mean in the window's file browser, in the open file window that pops up (i.e. ctrl-o), or the current folder window in the matlab interface?

Comment: It's a feature I'd like to have and I don't know if there's any way to get MATLAB doing it! :) I've attached a screenshot in the original post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay to answer it: I think there's no such a feature yet implemented, hopefully it will be in the future of matlab!